# How to edit minified javascript files in text editor without crash/hang on OSX

Tags: javascript, macos

Every text editor I have tried crashes, hangs, or runs extremely slowly when viewing and editing minified javascript files due to the long line length.

Is there a GUI text editor for OSX (not vi/vim/emacs) with soft line wrapping that can open/edit minified javascript files without freaking out?

Not a major problem for files less than a few 100 KB but when they get larger than a few MBs most editors seems to struggle even opening the files, displaying with soft line wraps, and auto-formatting.

Comment: Safari developer tools automatically pretty prints minified js files in resources view. Chrome can also pretty print any loaded js file but not automatically does that. You can also use any advanced IDE to reformat a minified file's source.

Answer (score 0):

So I did find this earlier today while browsing the VIM plugins site.  I'm not sure how large the file is but I imagine this might be able to help you.  https://vimawesome.com/plugin/largefile.  This comes with instructions for install.  If you need a hand installing the VIM plugin and configuring it please let me know, but it should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: These suggestions are sound but I am pretty slow using the command line for edits like this. I am looking for something to use a little more interactively, particularly for reviewing & debugging bundles created by webpack etc. Atom works great for files up to a hundred KBs but over 1 MB and it starts to hang.

Comment: Did you ever figure out another solution to this problem?

Comment: No, I haven't found any great solutions yet... I remain optimistic.

Comment: I just found a new method that might work for you earlier.  Let me know if it works.